# Should I call clearTimeout before overwriting the timeout variable?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Just found this code-snippet in our application. I am wondering if the first line is superfluous -- does one need to call clearTimeout on a variable if it is immediately overwritten? Or is there some condition I should be aware of?

```
function Countdown() {
    clearTimeout(sessionTimeoutHandle);
    sessionTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () { countdownHandler() }, MILLISECONDS);
}
```

My hunch is "Yes, you need to call clearTimeout" because I can't think of why the clearTimeout method would exist if it was OK to just set the timeout variable to null.

I suppose the better question is:

```
var timeoutHandler = setTimeout(countdownHandler, MILLISECONDS);
timeoutHandler = setTimeout(countdownHandler, MILLISECONDS);
```

Do I now have two functions waiting to fire in approximately MILLISECONDS, or just one?

Comment: `setTimeout(function () { countdownHandler() }, ...)` is superfluous, unless that's just for illustration.  It should be `setTimeout(countdownHandler, ...)`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Just getting basic questions out of the way before cleaning the code at all. :) Thank you though.

Comment: How is sessionTimeoutHandle initialized before the first setTimeout?

Comment: are you not getting a reference error from sessionTimeoutHandle? it hasnt been created yet in your before clearing??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you only need to call it if you actually need to clear it.

If this is the only code using that variable, then there should be no need.

---

FYI, it looks like you could shorten the code a bit...

```
function Countdown() {
    clearTimeout(sessionTimeoutHandle);
    sessionTimeoutHandle = setTimeout(countdownHandler, MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Nothing was gained with the anonymous function.

Comment: So if I call setTimeout and sessionTimeoutHandle is defined -- will the function it is a timer for still fired even though sessionTimeoutHandle has been overwritten with a new value?

Comment: @SeanAnderson yes, it'll still be fired - overwriting the handle doesn't prevent the original timer from firing - that's what `clearTimeout` is for.

Comment: @SeanAnderson: The value returned from `setTimeout` is just a `Number` primitive. It has no behaviors beyond any other number.

Comment: Okay. That is what I wanted to confirm. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Your call to setTimeout returns an integer to id it, so that you have a reference to it when you want to clear it. So overwriting the variable doesn't clear the timeout it just overwrites your reference to it's id. If you overwrite the reference you can no longer clear the earlier one :-(

You'll use clearTimeout as Niko says - to stop the callback from firing.

illustration:

```js
var t = setTimeout(ch, 1000, "first timeout");
t = setTimeout(ch, 1500, "second timeout");
clearTimeout(t); // this will only clear the second timeout
t = setTimeout(ch, 2000, "third timeout");
function ch(s){
  console.log(s);
}
```

I hope this is some help.

Comment: This should be selected as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I can't think of why the clearTimeout method would exist

`clearTimeout` exists to *cancel* an existing timer, i.e. to erase the timer and prevent its callback function from being invoked.

Answer (score 1):

clearTimeout is for canceling the timeout, not for freeing any memory or stuff like that. If you want to stop the timer, call clearTimeout - if you want it to finish or if it already did, there is no need to do so.